How to use sudo to run code on PetaLinux VSCode debugger?
I use sudo privileges to run C programs on PetaLinux. Like the example below.
$ sduo ./test.c

My petalinux version
$ uname -a
Linux petalinux_project 5.15.36-xilinx-v2022.2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 3 07:50:07 UTC 2022 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

Now I want to use the gdb debugger, but I don't know how to add sudo. If I don't run the debugger with sudo, my program will crash.
My launch.json is as follows:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": <exe_file_path>,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "valuesFormatting": "parseText",
        }
    ]
}

Could you please explain it to me? Thank you, everyone.

could try and replace the parameters with this:

{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/yourExecutable",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "",
            "runtimeExecutable": "sudo",
            "runtimeArgs": [],
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}




